# WAMP You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
I created a new virtual host for my project. And now I cant access all locally stored projects that I could access earlier. But project on virtual host works.

**http-vhosts.conf:**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my_poject.com
    DocumentRoot "c:\wampF\www\my_project\web"
    ServerName my_poject.com
    ErrorLog "logs/my_poject.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/my_poject.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts:**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1           localhost
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1 my_poject.com
```

Comment: Take a look at this post it will show you how to create Virtual Hosts properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Apache 2.4.

Use

`Require all granted`

instead of all

`Order allow,deny
Allow from all`

from your all .conf files
for eg-:http.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf, httpd-autoindex.conf like that.

Then restart your system.

Regds