# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /< on this server - Windows

Tags: php, server, permissions

Sorry guys I am extremely noob on this Apache setup. I have a Windows 10, 64 bit machine in which Apache24 is installed. When I try to test and kind of PHP code that involves "$_POST" superglobal it throws this error: "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /< on this server."

I checked a video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmKBRCTjOXE) and ([WAMP You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797967/wamp-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)) this link but I am not quite sure where to really add "Require all granted" to resolve this issue. The content of my "httpd-vhosts.conf" looks really different than the one shown on youtube. I added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

IN YOUR **httpd-vhosts.conf** FILE WRITE

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Your Site Path"
    ServerName yourdevsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then Open Your **HOST** FILE
YOU CAN FIND THIS FILE AT C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
 AND ADD THESE LINES

```
127.0.0.1 yourdevsite.com
```

That's it